# JHipster: Angular JS not being processed

Tags: java, angularjs, jhipster

I setup the project and added a new entity. The angular JS is not being processed. What could be the possible reason for this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if we answer angular translate support as no, jhipster doesn't work

Comment: What version of JHipster are you using? If this happens with the latest 2.x version, please enter an issue in GitHub. You also might want to try the just-released 3.0 version: http://jhipster.github.io/2016/03/23/jhipster-release-3.0.0.html